# fixing the repetitive wave structure in depth map when writing to disk

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision, ros2

My depth map has no problem when I visualize it using `rviz2` however when I save it using `astype(np.uint16)` after multiplying the depth values by `1000` as mentioned by the author of BundleSDF git repo here, it saves depth images in problematic shape.

If I use this script to save depth images:

```
from pathlib import Path
from rosbags.highlevel import AnyReader
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from datetime import datetime
from matplotlib import image
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



with AnyReader([Path('/home/mona/rosbag2_2023_11_06-15_44_24')]) as reader:
    connections = [x for x in reader.connections if x.topic == '/camera/camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw']

    for connection, timestamp, rawdata in reader.messages(connections=connections):
        msg = reader.deserialize(rawdata, connection.msgtype)
        timestamp_dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(msg.header.stamp.sec + msg.header.stamp.nanosec * 1e-9)
        timestamp_str = timestamp_dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")


        timestamp_ns = msg.header.stamp.sec * 1e9 + msg.header.stamp.nanosec
        numeric_timestamp = int(timestamp_ns / 1e-9)
        image_data = msg.data.reshape(480, 640,-1)*1000
        
        # Take only the first channel (grayscale)
        grayscale_image = image_data[:, :, 0]
        depth_image_name = 'depth/' + str(numeric_timestamp)[:20] + '.png'
        cv2.imwrite(depth_image_name, grayscale_image.astype(np.uint16))
```

I get this:

[image]

and if I use this slightly modified script to save images

```
from pathlib import Path
from rosbags.highlevel import AnyReader
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from datetime import datetime
from matplotlib import image
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with AnyReader([Path('/home/mona/rosbag2_2023_11_06-15_44_24')]) as reader:
    connections = [x for x in reader.connections if x.topic == '/camera/camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw']

    for connection, timestamp, rawdata in reader.messages(connections=connections):
        msg = reader.deserialize(rawdata, connection.msgtype)
        timestamp_dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(msg.header.stamp.sec + msg.header.stamp.nanosec * 1e-9)
        timestamp_str = timestamp_dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
        timestamp_ns = msg.header.stamp.sec * 1e9 + msg.header.stamp.nanosec
        numeric_timestamp = int(timestamp_ns / 1e-9)        
        w, h = msg.width, msg.height
        image_data = msg.data.reshape(h, w,-1)*1000
        
        # Take only the first channel (grayscale)
        grayscale_image = image_data[:, :, 0]
        depth_image_name = 'depth/' + str(numeric_timestamp)[:20] + '.png'
        depth_data = np.array(grayscale_image, dtype=np.uint16)
        image16 = cv2.UMat(depth_data)
        cv2.imwrite(depth_image_name, image16.get())
```

I get this:

[image]

My ros2 bag is healthy and has no problem. Also, since this was a depth aligned capture, the rgb images are healthy and saved in correct format.

How can I fix this problem and save the depth images correctly?

Related links:

1. https://github.com/NVlabs/BundleSDF/issues/82#issuecomment-1698248648
2. https://github.com/NVlabs/BundleSDF/issues/82#issuecomment-1699580570
3. https://github.com/NVlabs/BundleSDF/issues/74#issuecomment-1681430819

My cup data as shown by `identify` command is following the same format as `milk` data captured by author of BundleSDF git repo.

```
(base) mona@ada:~/BundleSDF/milk/2022-11-18-15-10-24_milk/depth$ identify ../../../cup/depth/16993034935581901703.png
../../../cup/depth/16993034935581901703.png PNG 640x480 640x480+0+0 16-bit Grayscale Gray 115375B 0.000u 0:00.000
(base) mona@ada:~/BundleSDF/milk/2022-11-18-15-10-24_milk/depth$ identify 1668813100171987935.png
1668813100171987935.png PNG 640x480 640x480+0+0 16-bit Grayscale Gray 49234B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Some system info:

```
(base) mona@ada:~$ ros2 wtf
/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ros2doctor/api/package.py: 112: UserWarning: joy has been updated to a new version. local: 3.1.0 < latest: 3.3.0
/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ros2doctor/api/package.py: 112: UserWarning: sdl2_vendor has been updated to a new version. local: 3.1.0 < latest: 3.3.0

All 5 checks passed
```

```
(base) mona@ada:~$ /usr/bin/python3.10
Python 3.10.12 (main, Jun 11 2023, 05:26:28) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
```

```
(base) mona@ada:~$ uname -a
Linux ada 6.2.0-36-generic #37~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Oct  9 15:34:04 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
(base) mona@ada:~$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

The RGB image saved looks like this:

[image]

The process for capture is:

1. open a terminal and type this command: `ros2 launch realsense2_camera rs_launch.py align_depth.enable:=true`
2. open a new terminal and type this command: `ros2 bag record -a`
3. press `CTL+C` to stop recording
4. run the script

checking the depth aligned capture in `rviz2` I see my `depth aligned depth raw image` and `raw color image` like the following and it doesn't seem if there is a problem:
[image]

These are the topics I am showing in `rviz2`:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Converting to uint16 means some loss of information from floating point, that produces the wavy pattern, maybe multiplying by 1000 is kind of wrong? What are the units of the original depth image? uint16 max value is 65536, so a value of 66, multiplied by 1000, would overflow and show the wavy pattern.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I do agree with you. The author multiplies the depth values by 1000 here and is a requirement for the depth map (he uses same/similar camera and ros realsense for capture too)
` cv2.imwrite('depth.png', (depth_meter*1000).astype(np.uint16))` 
https://github.com/NVlabs/BundleSDF/issues/82#issuecomment-1699580570

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy this line is the only other line I could find with notion of `depth_meter` and uint16 (by same author)  https://github.com/wenbowen123/iros20-6d-pose-tracking/blob/18dc5bac30024e4d44465f3202ba6ffbb62e8e3b/blender_dataset_generator.py#L249

Comment: Give it a try without multiplying by 1000, also in your last comment, you can see in the code they are clamping any depth beyond 2.0 to 0.0, which prevents any overflow of uint16. As I said, check the range of values in your original depth maps.

Comment: this is clearly integer wraparound from a larger range into a smaller one. converting *to* uint16 might not do anything *if* the data taken from the message is broken already. we'll need to know more about this data.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz what else do you need on my end? happy to share

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I was trying to follow instruction by Dr. Snoopy from this https://github.com/wenbowen123/iros20-6d-pose-tracking/blob/18dc5bac30024e4d44465f3202ba6ffbb62e8e3b/blender_dataset_generator.py#L249 it clamps depth data beyound 2.0 and 0.0 and I used inRange function from cv2 to do that I guess I may have used wrong function?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks a lot for pointing me towards realizing that inRange has caused the image to become binarized. I deleted my answer for same reason. As shown in git post, the histograms of binarized image made by me and the depth image sample provided by BundleSDF were wildly different. So the problem is still standing.

Comment: a direct dump (pickle) of `msg.data` would be useful to see

Comment: I resolved my problem by switching to ros noetic https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/105438/depth-aligned-capture-doesnt-yield-same-number-of-rgb-and-depth-frames-cv-br